# Parsing data from file

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, list, parsing

I wanted to parse a given file line by line. The file has a format of
`'name age gender hobby1 hobby2...'`.

The first thing that came to mind was to use a named tuple of the form `namedtuple('info',['name','age', 'gender','hobby'])`.

How can I save the data in my file to a list of tuples with the corresponding value. I tried using `line.split()` but I couldn't figure out how I can save the space separated hobbies to `info.hobby`.

[Input file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bI1W3.png)

Comment: please show whatever work you're done so far. it'll be a starting point for discussion. show data file, too. oh, and errors if any.

Comment: Can you post an excerpt? How is everything separated? Commas, Spaces, Tabs?

Comment: Please show what attempts you have made so far.

Comment: Please [edit] with the actual file contents

Comment: Whoops, this just loaded as I submitted an answer - take a look and clarify what you are trying to do with the data

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you can use pandas and pass 'this_is_a_space' as the sep if data is like this:

```
name age gender hobby1 hobby2
steve 12 male xyz abc
bob 29 male swimming golfing
alice 40 female reading cooking
tom 50 male sleeping
```

and here is syntax for method described above:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep=' ')
df.fillna(' ', inplace=True)
df['hobby'] = df[['hobby1', 'hobby2']].apply(lambda i: ' '.join(i), axis=1)
df.drop(['hobby1', 'hobby2'], axis=1, inplace=True)

print df
```

out:

```
    name  age  gender             hobby
0  steve   12    male           xyz abc
1    bob   29    male  swimming golfing
2  alice   40  female   reading cooking
3    tom   50    male        sleeping
```

EDIT:  added your data from comment above

Comment: Yes but I wanted to have all the hobbies under one field name. meaning insted of hobby1 hobby2, I want the output to have just one hobby field and list them as [xyz abc]